# doNothing() method is calling actual method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to doNothing() when a final void method is called, but the doNothing() call is calling the actual method instead.

SwitchWorker class

```
public class SwitchWorker {

    public boolean switchMethod(String id){
        this.methodA(id);
        return true;
    }

    public void methodA(String id){
        final Switch switchObj = Switch.getSwitchInstance(); 
        switchObj.finalVoidMethod(id);
        // XYZ......
    }
}
```

Switch Class

```
public final class Switch {
    private static final Switch INSTANCE = new Switch();
    private Switch() { //Private Constructor
        super();
    }
    public static Switch getSwitchInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    public final synchronized void finalVoidMethod(String param) {
        // Do Something
    }    
}
```

Test code:

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.application.switching.Switch")
 public class SwitchWorkerTest {

        @Test
        public void test() throws Exception {
            SwitchWorker swObj = new SwitchWorker();

            final String channelId = "0001";

            Switch switchMock = mock(Switch.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Switch.class);
            when(Switch.getSwitchInstance()).thenReturn(switchMock);

            doNothing().when(switchMock).finalVoidMethod(channelId);

            boolean result = swObj.switchMethod(channelId);
            assertTrue(result);                            
        }
```

Am I missing anything for the doNothing() method?

```
"doNothing().when(switchMock).finalVoidMethod(channelId);"
```

doNothing() is calling the actual finalVoidMethod() instead of mocking. But, switchMock is a Mocked object.

I've looked at almost every question on stack overflow regarding PowerMockito, mocking static methods, and doNothing methods, I'm not sure if I'm missing anything as I've followed most examples to build the code. I've added @PrepareForTest too but later removed it.

Thank you.

edit: I snipped the code to be more abstract and changed slightly to fit @kswaughs comment

```
public boolean mockedMethod(final String input) {
    System.out.println("0----------------------");
    final Switch switchObj = Switch.getSwitchInstance();
    System.out.println("1:switchObj: "+ switchObj);
    switches.refresh("input");
    System.out.println("2----------------------");
    return true;
}
```

With test code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Switch.class, SwitchWorker.class})
public class SwitchWorkerTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        SwitchWorker swObj = new SwitchWorker();

        Switch switchMock = mock(Switch.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Switch.class);
        when(Switch.getSwitchInstance()).thenReturn(switchMock);
        boolean result = swObj.mockedMethod("0001");
        assertTrue(result);
```

returns .

```
0----------------------
1:switchObj: Mock for Switch, hashCode: 1659309731

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.application.switching.Switch.refresh(Switch.java:238)
at com.application.switching.SwitchWorker$1.run(SwitchWorker.java:51)
```

Comment: Is the static import for doNothing() and when() being imported from Mockito or PowerMockito? Mockito cannot mock a final method, so if the import is plain Mockito then that could be a reason this is not working.

Comment: I've tried both, even switched "doNothing()" to "PowerMockito.doNothing()" to double check but it's still calling the original method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing all the methods to use PowerMockito, I realized that the mock object itself was initialised using Mockito.

Changing:

```
Switch switchMock = mock(Switch.class);
```

to (or changing the imports):

```
Switch switchMock = PowerMockito.mock(Switch.class);
```

fixed my problem.

Thanks to the people who contributed (The small things like this are my bane)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your example and it is working for me properly. Two things to be remembered here.

1. When you mock an object, the methods of the mock object will not get executed and by default returns null if they have any return type. For a void method, you don't have to set expectations explicitly.
2. To mock a final class, you have to declare it in prepareForTest.

Please check if you have compatible versions of both mockito & powermockito.

I ran your example as below.

**Maven**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Test code**

```
package com.kswaughs;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Switch.class)
public class SwitchWorkerTest {

   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception {
       SwitchWorker swObj = new SwitchWorker();

       final String channelId = "0001";

       Switch switchMock = mock(Switch.class);
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(Switch.class);
       when(Switch.getSwitchInstance()).thenReturn(switchMock);

       boolean result = swObj.switchMethod(channelId);
       Assert. assertTrue(result);                            
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. From what I've gathered, you've added PrepareForTest for the Switch class (because its a final class) and removed the SuppressStaticInitialization for the Switch class. Additionally, you removed the doNothing method because mocked objects naturally return null for void methods.

After doing what you suggested and playing around with your code, I'm still getting the same issue. I've checked my pom file and have both mockito and powermockito dependancies too.

Answer (score -1):

doNothing() method will calling actual method, if you don't want call, you can use [suppress-method](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior#suppress-method).it will suppress no-return method to call.

```
doNothing().when(switchMock).finalVoidMethod(channelId);
```

change

```
suppress(method(SwitchWorker.class, "finalVoidMethod"));
```